# How to check if dark mode is enabled on iOS/Android using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I check if dark mode is enabled in **Android Q** with **Flutter**?
 I know how to set the dark mode, but I didn't find a way to check the background theme.
Here is the code to set the dark theme.

```
darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
```

Answer (score 287, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. **NO `context` required**. Can be used in `initState` for example:

   ```
   var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
   bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
   ```
2. **`context` is required**:

   ```
   var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
   bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
   ```

   or

   ```
   var brightness = View.of(context).platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
   bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this solution doesn't work and crashes the app.

Comment: Where did you use this code? You can put it in your `build()` method, and if the crashes again, please post the stack trace because it is working for me.

Comment: I put it in the build() method, but it always returns 'Normal mode'. I have a Switch Widget for changing the theme from light to dark.

Comment: In which phone are you testing this, do mention the Android version?

Comment: Pocophone F1 with Android Pie and the Android Emulators Api Versions 27,28 and 29. I have to mention that I am using custom themes, but tried the code with the default themes, too.

Comment: The only way for this code to 'crash' the app is to use an invalid context.

Comment: @Ovidiu Yes you're right the app would crash for an invalid context, so you should use this in either `build()` or after `build()` is finished like using `addPostFrameCallback`.

Comment: Don't forget to import this for #1:  import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart'; and 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Comment: SchedulerBinding.instance!.window.platformBrightness; is best solution to check theme of system in main before runapp() called.

Comment: It's better to use WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness. Otherwise some platform may resort to returning Brightness.light, as the instance.window is not applicable.

Answer (score 45):

With the introduction of [Extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) in Dart, I prefer to append that functionality to `BuildContext` directly. This provides a cleaner feeling interface and reads much better.

```dart
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

extension DarkMode on BuildContext {
  /// is dark mode currently enabled?
  bool get isDarkMode {
    final brightness = MediaQuery.of(this).platformBrightness;
    return brightness == Brightness.dark;
  }
}
```

Then in my build functions I can use it easily.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final Widget logo = SvgPicture.asset(
      context.isDarkMode ? "assets/logo_dark.svg" : "assets/logo.svg",
      semanticsLabel: 'my logo');
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If you define a dark theme in your `MaterialApp`, your app will automatically go dark when Android Q dark theme is enabled. You have to specify your dark theme like this:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
);
```

According to [this medium article](https://medium.com/flutter/android-dark-theme-in-flutter-9c8070b8b127),

> Now when you toggle Dark Theme in your system drawer, your Flutter app will automatically switch from your regular theme to your darkTheme!

However, if you want to manually check whether you're on dark mode, you can easily write a method using the Platform Channel API. More details [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). As for the native code, [check here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme).

Answer (score 16):

I found the way. Here it is.

```
  bool _darkModeEnabled = false;

  void _checkIfDarkModeEnabled() {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    theme.brightness == appDarkTheme().brightness
        ? _darkModeEnabled = true
        : _darkModeEnabled = false;
  }
```

Update 27.02.23:

```
final brightness = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
```

Comment: There are 2 different things, one is you set the theme on your own like light or dark and you can check it using `Theme` object, one is you fetch the theme applied in Phone settings (available only in Android Pie dark mode), for this you use `MediaQuery`.

Comment: Your code checks the brightness of the theme that your app is using. This is not what the question is about - the question is about the operating system-driven light/dark mode. `MaterialApp` has 3 related properties: `theme`, `darkTheme` and `themeMode`. If `themeMode` is not `system` or `darkTheme` is null, then the brightness of the app's theme will be `light` even if the OS (Android 10+/iOS 13+) has dark mode enabled. @CopsOnRoad has the correct answer.

Comment: You should clarify what appDarkTheme is.

Comment: This is checking the brightness of the theme which is set, which does not really tell the system preferences.

Answer (score 14):

> How can I check if dark mode is enabled

Answer:

`Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark`

Comment: This option is the only one that actually works in 2023. Others do not show the updated value!

Comment: This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ThemeMode` inside `MaterialApp`.

```
MaterialApp(
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
  theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: Colors.red,
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
);
```

`ThemeMode.system` will get the active theme in the OS and then either use the `theme` or `darkTheme`. Additionally `ThemeMode.dark` will always use the `darkTheme` and `ThemeMode.light` will always use the `theme`.

Comment: Sorry! This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: but it helps to understand what is what!

Answer (score 5):

No matter what the current platform is, if you have access to `context` you can simply check it by using `Theme`. Following is sample that I used to change white color to transparent color if currently app theme is `dark`.

```
(Theme.of(context) == Brightness.dark) ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent
```

Comment: It worked for me with Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark .. but this answer is the best one I could find with the least amount of code

Comment: For anyone else coming here, this answer and Gummy Bear's addition of 'Theme.of(context).brightness' makes this the far simplest option that I've found

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Getx state management, then don't worry because Getx provided solution

```
bool ThemeModes(){
Get.isDarkMode? return true: return false;}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code

```
Brightness brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness
bool isDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
bool isLightMode = brightness == Brightness.light;
```

Comment: Don't waste your time with this code, it doesn't check the System's theme.

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that `MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness` will cause rebuilding on all media queries events including screen size changed, rotation, popup keyboard, ...

Instead, `MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf` only rebuild when system dark mode changes:

```dart
final brightness = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context);
final systemDarkMode = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check OS theme mode: (if using `ThemeMode.system`)

```
Brightness brightness =  MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance.window).platformBrightness;
bool darkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

or using theme

```
Brightness brightness = Theme.of(context).brightness
bool darkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

set brightness in `MaterialApp`

```
theme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
  ),
darkTheme: ThemeData(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool _darkModeEnabled = false;
bool _lightModeEnabled = false;

void _checkIfDarkModeEnabled() {
final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
theme.brightness == Brightness.dark
    ? _darkModeEnabled = true
    : _darkModeEnabled = false;
}
void _checkIfLightModeEnabled() {
final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
theme.brightness == Brightness.light
    ? _lightModeEnabled = true
    : _lightModeEnabled = false;
}
```

Comment: This is checking the brightness of set theme and not the system preference. Also why do you need two methods ? you can just call one method and set both values there itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using https://github.com/arthurdenner/theme_mode_handler, and the right way to check if it's set on system first, otherwise we check the theme handler:

```
bool is_dark(BuildContext context){
  if(ThemeModeHandler.of(context)!.themeMode == ThemeMode.system)
    return (Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark);
  else
    return ThemeModeHandler.of(context)!.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me forked, at least the version with the AdaptiveTheme plugin.

```
Theme.of(context) == darkThemeData

AdaptiveTheme.of(context).theme == darkThemeData
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work even you change the app theme mode manually within your app.
Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark

Answer (score 0):

Use this
Theme.of(context).brightness

Answer (score -1):

If you are using GetX package for flutter already, then you can simply use the context extension method already provided in there which is

```
context.isDarkMode
```

GetX has many useful extension methods prebuilt. Thought I should mention this.