# Detect if OS dark mode is active

Tags: flutter, detect, darkmode

I am looking a way to detect if OS dark mode is active, using Flutter. I just want my app to follow the OS dark mode setting. I've googling it and most of the topics are about "setting & switching" dark mode, not about detect the OS' dark mode.

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304215/how-to-check-if-android-or-ios-dark-mode-is-enabled-in-flutter

Comment: the essence of the question is the same, but at that thread, the answer is not perfect, not working with old phone (red screen error). luckily I got reliable answer this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `platformBrightness` to detect current mode of OS

```
bool isDarkMode() {
    final darkMode = WidgetsBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness;
    if (darkMode == Brightness.dark) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working perfectly. I've try it using old phone and new phone. In old phone that the OS doesn't support dark mode, it return "false", which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your build method

```
var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
bool darkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it looks like doesn't work with old phone that the OS doesn't support dark mode, it give "red screen" error.