# How to change theme in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I'm trying here to get the current theme, if it's light or dark.
So I can change widget color accordingly..
However, it doesn't work, I used if statment to know when it's dark mode..
but it's always False ..
This is the code.. btw it switch between dark & light theme..
but when i try to get current theme.. even if the theme changed to dark..
the if statments always show false...

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    bool darkModeOn = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    Color containerColor;
    if (darkModeOn == true) {
      containerColor = Colors.blueGrey;
      print("----------------");
      print("dark mode ON");
      print("----------------");
    } else {
      containerColor = Colors.deepPurple;
      print("LIGHT mode ON");
    }

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            //----switch theme---
            currentTheme.switchTheme();
          },
          label: Text(
            "Switch theme",
            style: TextStyle(
            ),
          ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.color_lens_outlined),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DarkXLight"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Expanded(child: Container(
              color: containerColor,
            ),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't switch themes like that. You will need to handle the logic in the `MaterialApp` otherwise

```dart
MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
```

will always return `true`/`false` based on what was provided to the `MaterialApp.themeMode`.

Here's a sample code to get started. I used `ValueListenableBuilder` but you can also use `provider`.

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> _notifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.light);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
      valueListenable: _notifier,
      builder: (_, mode, __) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.light(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          themeMode: mode, // Decides which theme to show, light or dark.
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => _notifier.value = mode == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
                child: Text('Toggle Theme'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm able to switch themes.. now I'm trying to get the current theme ( light or dark ), from another class.. so I can change the container color when the theme change

Comment: @SilentFairy "I'm able to switch themes" -- Can you tell me what your `bool darkModeOn` returns on changing themes? Your question title needs to be changed otherwise it would become a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56304215/6618622)

Comment: my main question is how to get current theme from anywhere in app.  `bool darkModeOn` returns false. Always!

Comment: @SilentFairy That means you were not able to change the theme, which is why your question should be "How to change theme".

Comment: Thank you, I changed it.. but now I'm confused.. I know I can change the theme from MaterialApp the main page. (Which works because scaffold & button color changed ) but when I try to get current theme from any other class.. it doesn't work ^^

Comment: @SilentFairy Can you post a minimal code of your issue, I can definitely help you better.

Comment: you were right! the switch theme functions wasn't working as expected thats why `bool darkModeOn` return always false. So ! I searched on YT the right way to switch themes, then it works! I added full code here

Answer (score 2):

So, I was able to solve my problem..
I will put the code so if someone faced the same issue..
I simply, changed the way I used to switch themes. It was wrong..
However, here I'm posting the Correct way & this way solved the problem..

***MAIN PAGE***

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice_darkmode/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'MyHomePage.dart';

Future<void> main() async {

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
      builder: (context, _) {
        final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
          darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
          themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
          home: MyHomePage(),
        );
      },
    );

  }
}
```

***Theme Provider class***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//---This to switch theme from Switch button----
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  //-----Store the theme of our app--
  ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;

  //----If theme mode is equal to dark then we return True----
  //-----isDarkMode--is the field we will use in our switch---
  bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

  //---implement ToggleTheme function----
  void toggleTheme(bool isOn) {

  themeMode = isOn ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;

  //---notify material app to update UI----
  notifyListeners();
}

}

//---------------Themes settings here-----------
class MyThemes {

  //-------------DARK THEME SETTINGS----
  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black45,
    // colorScheme:  ColorScheme.dark(),

  );


  //-------------light THEME SETTINGS----
  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    //colorScheme:  ColorScheme.light(),
  );

}
```

***Change Theme button widget class ( this is to create a switch button)***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice_darkmode/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class ChangeThemeButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //----First we want to get the theme provider----
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);

    return Switch.adaptive(
      //---isDarkMode to return if its dark or not--true or false--
      value: themeProvider.isDarkMode,
      onChanged: (value) {
        final provider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context, listen: false);
        provider.toggleTheme(value);
      },
      activeColor: themeProvider.isDarkMode ? Colors.purple : Colors.green,

    );

  }
}
```

***Home Page***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:practice_darkmode/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'ChangeThemeButtonWidget.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    dynamic text;
    dynamic textColor;
    dynamic appBarColor;
    dynamic btnColor;
    dynamic appBarTextColor;

    if (Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode == ThemeMode.dark) {

      text = "IT'S DARK ";
      textColor = Colors.cyanAccent;
      appBarColor = Colors.black;
      btnColor = Colors.deepPurple;
      appBarTextColor = Colors.cyanAccent;

    } else if (Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode == ThemeMode.light) {

      text = "IT'S LIGHT ";
      textColor = Colors.red;
      appBarColor = Colors.red;
      btnColor = Colors.red;
      appBarTextColor = Colors.white;

    }

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
          },
          label: Text(
            "Switch theme",
            style: TextStyle(
            ),
          ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.color_lens_outlined),
        backgroundColor: btnColor,
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("DarkXLight", style: TextStyle(color: appBarTextColor),),
        backgroundColor: appBarColor,
        actions: [
          ChangeThemeButtonWidget(),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "$text!",
            style: (
            TextStyle(
              fontSize: 27,
              color: textColor,
            )
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You could have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185945/6618622).

Answer (score 1):

Below code will to change theme via Icon Button in appBar. Steps:

1. Create a stateful widget.
2. Add the following variables:

```
bool _iconBool = false;
IconData _iconLight = Icons.wb_sunny;
IconData _iconDark = Icons.nights_stay;
```

3. Create actions -> IconButton in the appBar as below:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Simple Colregs"),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF5B4B49).withOpacity(0.8),
          actions: [
            IconButton(icon: Icon(_iconBool ? _iconDark : _iconLight),
              },)
          ],
        ), //AppBar
```

4. Add Below methods with Light and Dark themes and any custom preference is required:

```
// light Theme
ThemeData lightThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFF5B4B49),
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Color(0xFF24A751)));
}

// dark Theme
ThemeData darkThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
      primaryColor: Color(0xFFFF1D00),
      colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Color(0xFF24A751)));
}
```

Read more about ThemeData Class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html).

5. Under IconButton, create a functionality for the button as below which will toggle the theme:

```
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _iconBool = !_iconBool;

                });
```

6. Finally add under Material App:

```
theme: _iconBool ? lightThemeData(context) : darkThemeData(context),
```

That's all, good to go. Hope it helps.

Comment: are you sure this works? I've done exactly this and its not switching it. The variable is switching correctly but its as if the app isn't fully rebuilding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in initState

```
bool darkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;

or

var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
bool darkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;
```