# How to change theme with Switch?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, uiswitch

I am implementing switch to change Theme in my application.
As switch value I am using  `Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark` and switch it's not working (I can drag switch but he is coming back to his position)

When I change value to `Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light` switch is working but I need it in first option.

here is my switch code:

```
Switch(
                              value: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark,
                              onChanged: (brightness) async {
                                print(brightness);
                                await MySecureStorage().writeData('theme', brightness ? 'dark' : 'light');
                                Provider.of<MainProvider>(context, listen: false).changeThemeMode(brightness ? ThemeMode.light : ThemeMode.dark);
                                SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
                                                     SystemUiOverlayStyle(
                                                         statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                         statusBarIconBrightness: brightness
                                                             ? Brightness.dark
                                                             : Brightness.light
                                                     )
                                );
                              },
                            )
```

and why is compared to `Brightness.dark` it's not working? What I am missing?

Comment: will always return true/false based on what was provided to the MaterialApp.themeMode.
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794181/how-to-change-theme-in-flutter)

Comment: But why when I set value to ```== Brightness.light``` switch is working and it's changing theme?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it's embarrasing but I didn't change parameters in Provider function.
It was the problem