# What is the best way to tell if my app is in dark mode in my llibrary?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So, I have created a gitlab repo for some components like a StandardCard and that's how I'm checking if my app is in dark mode or not so I can use custom colors according to that:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var brightness = MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
    bool isDarkMode = brightness == ThemeMode.light ? false : true;   
    return MyWidget();
  }
```

The thing is, my component is not receiving the correct platformBrightness. I don't know if the context of my build method of the component is the same as the one my app uses but I'd like to know what is a good way to check if my app is in darkMode or not without having to pass a context as a parameter of each one of the many StandardCard s I use in my app.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68680939/16757199) and see if this can help archive your goal.

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried but it just wasn't working. I was getting ThemeMode.light no matter what. I set a static ThemeMode object to my lib when the app is starting and it worked. But thanks anyways @HinsonT